# how to call a method with parameter Action(Of T) with variable

Tags: vb.net

I am in the process of converting some c# code to vb.net and I keep running into an issue with a particular method.
Here is the c# method signature -

```
public void DoSomething(Action<T> something)
{ .... do something in here }
```

Here is my vb.net conversion of the signature -

```
Public Sub DoSomething(ByVal something As Action(Of T))
    ....do something in here
End Sub
```

I have to call this with a variable.  Here is a sample c# call -

```
_myobject.DoSomething(x => { newValue = x.CallSomeMethod() });
```

How would I perform this same call using Vb.Net?
I've tried this (along with a few variations), but the newValue object is always empty -

```
_myObject.DoSomething(Sub(x) newValue = x.CallSomeMethod())
```

I've also tried this -

```
_myObject.DoSomething(Function(x) newValue = x.CallSomeMethod() End Function)
```

If I do this -

```
 _myObject.DoSomething(Function(x) newValue = x.CallSomeMethod())
```

I get an error message stating `Cannot apply operator '=' to operands of type myType and myType`

Comment: `newvalue` *should* be nothing/null  `CallSomeMethod` is not a function, nothing is returned to be assigned to `newvalue`

Comment: CallSomeMethod is a function - it returns data.  I can actually confirm that data is returned, but newValue never gets that data.

Comment: `public void...` and `Public Sub` define it as a Sub not Function

Comment: See edits - I've tried also defining it as Function, but the value is still not set.

Comment: `DoSomething` is a void method (C#) or Sub (VB): `public void DoSomething...` and `Public Sub DoSomething...`  All your edit changes is the nature of the parameter passed to it.  `CallSomeMethod` doesnt return anything to `newvalue`

Comment: If I wrap the parameter in Action(Of MyType)() as mentioned below by MotoSV, I still don't get any value in newValue.  DoSomething is a void method, but it basically just invokes the action passed in as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SourceClass` has the `DoSomething` method and the `TargetClass` has the `CallSomeMethod` that will be called as part of the anonymous `Sub`:

```
Public Class SourceClass

    Public Sub DoSomething(ByRef something As Action(Of TargetClass))
        Dim t As New TargetClass
        something(t)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class TargetClass
    Function CallSomeMethod() As Integer
        Return 1000
    End Function
End Class
```

In the `Main` method add this:

```
Public Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim newValue = 11
        Dim myObject = New SourceClass

        myObject.DoSomething(New Action(Of TargetClass)(Sub(obj) newValue = obj.CallSomeMethod()))

        Debug.WriteLine(newValue)

    End Sub    

End Module
```

In this example `newValue` will be assigned 1000.

Comment: I've tried that as well, but newValue is still empty.

Comment: I have updated the sample code. I have made some assumptions on the contents of the `DoSomething` and `CallSomeMethod` methods.

Comment: Ultimately, the issue was a bad contract in another part of my app that was causing the trouble.  However, the solution shown by MotoSV does answer my question and will do as shown above.